# Create Sub Admin in Django with Special Permission based on the Data

Tags: django

I am using Django 2.1

I want to create a few users with some special privileges, I call these users as "Manager". What a Manager can do is:

1. Can able to login Admin site (Can do this by making this user as staff)
2. Can do CRUD operation ONLY for his team. In a database I've created a table called "team", where every user is associated with the certain team.

Though it is not necessary to have a manager in each team. But if there is a manager he can do above-mentioned operations.

I am a bit confused about how to achieve that, as on Admin Panel I can create permissions and groups based on pages/models but not type of data (team-based).

I assume that I need to create different User types, but there are so many ways out there to handle different situations I am unable to relate if any one of them is applicable to my use case.

**Research:**

1. By creating a seperate tables for each user: [Multiple User Types In Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620811/multiple-user-types-in-django)

OR

[django best approach for creating multiple type users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users)

2. Could be done this way, where we create teams in the database, and allow manager to view the team data using overriding the queryset:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

3. Nested relationship using Serializers

[Handling different levels of nesting in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917847/handling-different-levels-of-nesting-in-django-rest-framework)

Can you please let me know what is the best approach to get this done. Thank you.

Comment: How does creating user types help you with this problem? If i understood it correctly, you want a User to be able to have CRUD rights on an instance (a manager can only update his team), right?

Comment: Exactly, but I mean to say, a manager and his team are from the same team, team A. Not sure, but this could be a user type based on team. Also, there are manager and normal user too

Comment: I can give more information if you want, thanks for your comment

Comment: For this specific case, you dont need different types of users. What you need is object level permissions, which you can use [Django Guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/assign.html#assign-obj-perms) for that.

Comment: Looks good @fxgx, I will have a look. Thank you for sharing